# What is the best log rotator for Python wsgi applications?

Tags: linux, python

I am running a wsgi based application that has concurrent users accessing it. For my logs needs I tried logrotate but found that logrotate is not too friendly to Python applications, so I tried using RotatingFileHandler and even worse found my logs all chopped up and part of it went missing!

I am considering ConcurrentRotatingFileHandler, my question is, has anyone out there experienced the same thing and better yet do you have any battle tested solution for Python wsgi, concurrently accessed applications?

Answer (score 0):

What was the problem with logrotate ? You may have a look at chronolog. It's mostly for web logs.

Answer (score 0):

if you use a newer version of python the logging module has support to rotate logs.

```
# Add the log message handler to the logger
handler = logging.handlers.RotatingFileHandler(
          LOG_FILENAME, maxBytes=20, backupCount=5)
```

look at http://docs.python.org/library/logging.html

i assume you use a built in web server as CherryPy.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I used it initially but I found my logs all butchered up and could not make head or tails of the logs. I used the usual settings of 'a' and 2 for logs.